# Atmospheric correction of larger collection of Sentinel 2 L1C images (in Google Earth Engine) for NDVI time series

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, sentinel-2, atmospheric-correction, cloud-cover

System: Windows 10

Software: Google Earth Engine browser, (QGIS, SNAP)

Data: Sentinel 2 L1C & L2A, NDVI calculations

I'm currently working on generating a NDVI timeseries in Google Earth Engine for 135 points in an area which is about 750m². I want to do this with Sentinel 2 imagery, starting in 2015.
Since L2A imagery only starts at dec 2018, I want to atmospherically correct all L1C images of my ROI before that timeperiod, but so far I have only found methods to correct the images one-by-one in programs such as FMask and SNAP with Sen2Cor.

I know that these programs produce images of similar quality as the L2A images, but is there a program or script that can correct more images at once (also with a method like Sen2Cor), preferably in Google Earth Engine?

Comment: I assume the L2A imagery already in EE doesn't have enough coverage for you? https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR

Comment: Hi @DanielWiell, it would not be ideal to only use those images, too short of a timespan. I'm aiming at 4-5 years. One thing I'm considering is combining with Landsat 8 for intermediate values or even prior values, but one could dedicate a new thread to that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used the PEPS database for all L1C images at https://peps.cnes.fr/rocket, which is now down as well but I just found this tool that might help finding a proper database: https://github.com/CS-SI/eodag. The advantage of PEPS was that one could convert all L1C images of my tile to L2A with the MAJA algorithm server-side. After correction I downloaded all my images with arja2, converted them to tifs with the GDAL package in Python, and then batch uploaded with the 'geeup'package of Samapriya Roy to a personal image collection in Google Earth Engine: https://zenodo.org/record/3991316#.YFCOpJ1Ki88.